# How to linkage between bar chart and pie chart in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

In PowerBI, we designed the bar chart is the first level, and some pie charts are the second level. They share the same data source. How to achieve the linkage between the bar chart and the pie chart?
I meaning when i click the bar chart,then the pie chart will changed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

in powerbi, when the desired value is pressed on the bar chart, that slice on the pie chart already appears, there is no need to do anything extra as it appears in the photo

Comment: Thanks,lkranur Büşra Aybuğa. I agree what your suggestion. Thanks agin. But the par chart also will impact bar chart. So there is no first level and 2nd level.